# How to get photo info on flickr?

Tags: php, flickr

how do I get information about a photo like the author, the license using PHP?

Answer (score 4):

You call a HTTP REST query, and load the results as a string:

```
$query = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=" . API_KEY . "&photo_id=" . $photoid . "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));

echo "created by: " . data->photo->owner->username;
echo "link to photopage: " . "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" . data->photo->owner->nsid; . "/" . data->photo->id;
```

You do this for whatever pieces of data you need from whichever REST calls you require.

All of this is available via the [flickr api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)

Answer (score 3):

This information is all available through the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), if you poke around their docs you may find what you're looking for.

Comment: how do I use the Flickr API with php?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Flickr's publically avaliable API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). Sign up for an API key then have a look at [this page](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.php.html) (which gives you a basic introduction to contacting the API and parsing serialized PHP. Personally I prefer using XML with SimpleXML).

You may find it easier to use one of the following packages:

- [PEAR](http://code.iamcal.com/php/flickr/readme.htm)
- [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/)
- [phlickr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phlickr/) (PHP5)

Consult the documentation for info on using them.